# Minecraft has gone gold

Tags: discussion, minecraft, obsolete-questions

...so it's time to do a mass clean up of our Minecraft content, yes?

We have two options:

1. You flag outdated questions (= about items or mechanisms that are no longer there, etc) and we delete them.

   - The homepage should not get trashed by question and answer deletion.
   - Some reputation will be lost
   - People opting to use old versions of Minecraft on purpose will have no use in our site.
2. We retag outdated questions to, say, [minecraft-pre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pre) or [old-minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-minecraft)

   - Less content is lost
   - There is a very real risk of trashing the homepage
   - We'll still need to delete outdated answers on current questions

What poison should we pick?

Comment: oh ye gods. This is going to be a pain.

Comment: Why the need to retag/delete old questions at all? If they've already got the version number in the question, what's the issue?

Comment: @RavenDreamer That's a huge 'if'

Comment: Don't we have a generic tag for this, like [tag:obsolete] or [tag:old-version] or [tag:outdated]? Should we, maybe?

Comment: @MartinSojka Sounds like a bad metatag to me.

Comment: btw, why retag to another tag? Why not just adda disclaimer on outdated questions and/or answers? It's both more informative to random users, and it prevents splitting the tags.

Comment: I vote option 2. It seems less destructive.

Comment: Note that we may still have this problem later as I read that Notch is going to keep updating it.

Comment: @John I'm willing to bet that Minecraft is going to be much stabler now than it's been in the past, but there's only one way to know.

Comment: Looks like it's time to revisit all my old Minecraft answers to see if they involve any old mechanics. (Gradually, of course.)

Comment: I'm saddened but also strangely liberated at the realization that I don't care in the slightest about the release.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think going gold should be that different from beta with a game like Minecraft. So I vote doing the same thing we did [the previous time something like this was raised](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2306/should-questions-about-obsoleted-mechanics-be-simply-removed):

1. If an answer is outdated, edit in a disclaimer.
2. If a question is outdated, edit in a disclaimer, and no further disclaimer is needed for its answers.

Either closing as too localized or protecting is also okay, I guess, but honestly I don't really see any benefit of doing that.

I'm against retagging, I don't think it's a good idea, we'll end up with a bunch of [agame](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agame) and [agame-beta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agame-beta) tag pairs, which won't really benefit anyone.

Comment: Editing sounds like a good idea if you have like, two or three or even a dozen posts. This problem is a few orders of magnitude larger than that.

Comment: @badp but how many of them truly require updating? I confess ignorance regarding Minecraft versions...

Comment: Personally, I don't think this version will be all that different from past ones, so I see no need to do anything different.

Comment: +1 to this.  The front page has been 95% Skyrim for days, I don't see how a few or even dozens of Minecraft edits could hurt.

Comment: @Oak — Knowing how many of them need updating is exactly the problem.  Chances are, most of them don't, but we can't pick out those that do without checking each of the [~800 questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft).  I agree that deleting or retagging is a worse option, but reviewing isn't ideal, either.  :-/

Comment: @Ben but luckily many of the answerers are active users. Active users tend to fix their own answers when new versions come up.