# As of 2019 am I allowed to ask about speculative lore on Arqade?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I've recently become very interested in the Bloodsouls lore and this got me to thinking:

**Can I ask about questions about speculative lore on Arqade?**

I've read through questions already asked on the meta and [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7696/should-lore-questions-as-an-entire-category-be-banned) it says that lore is allowed but does that include speculative lore? And that question was answered in 2013, is it the same today?

On the [help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about what is on-topic to ask it states:

- Plot and characters in games

So with the first one says I can ask about plot and characters but does this mean plots that haven't been proven just theorized (but strongly reinforced with evidence in the game)?

[This](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8014/how-should-i-reword-a-question-that-has-a-canonical-answer-but-has-been-put-on) question caught my eye with the blockquote:

> This includes speculative questions about developer intent, as well as lore questions not addressed directly through in-universe sources.

This is what he was told when [his question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/143434/559) was put on hold. Does this mean that I am allowed to ask lore questions that have possible answers backed with in-universe items such as item descriptions etc. ?

I Apologize if this is a duplicate (especially if its a duplicate of the questions I have linked haha) but I've been reading a lot and am still unsure of the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite what some people are saying, lore questions are on-topic on this site. However, as with any question on this site, you need to be mindful of how you ask the question to make sure it *stays* on-topic. This is especially true of lore questions, since there are a few members on the site who are not fond of lore questions and actively try to close them for any reason they can find.

Speculative lore is not completely off-topic, but you have to be careful how you ask. For example, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/340140/145980) is asking about the relation between two characters which is never really explained in any game. However, if you do ask a question like this, be sure that you're **not** looking for a discussion. "This info is not known" is a valid (and often times the only) answer.

As a general rule for "speculative" lore questions, if you think the answer to your question is probably somewhere within the game or its immediate references (the game's official website, a player's guide, etc.) then you're probably okay with asking it. However, if the answer is probably something that can't be answered except by the game designers, then it's off-topic.

Comment: I think this was the kind of answer I was looking for. Very informative, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

While lore itself is allowed without problems, speculation enters the opinion based area, so it is not a good place to ask these kind of things.

Comment: So while speculative lore is controversial it is definitely on-topic for Arqade?

Comment: Anything that can't be answered with 100% certainty is off-topic on Arqade.

Comment: @Wrigglenite So Speculative lore is on-topic yes, but if it doesn't have a proveable answer its off topic? How is the the questioner supposed to know if it is possible to be answered with 100% certainty? Sorry haha, just confused.

Comment: Speculative questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Thank you.

Answer (score -5):

Anything that can get more than five close votes is de facto off-topic here.

While lore questions are off-topic on Arqade because they don't work in the site format, they are on topic on other Stack Exchange sites because they do work in their identical format.

You're better off asking questions on those other sites. [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) would find this on-topic and probably give you more and better answers than you'd get here. [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) are also worth mentioning- they've been great at answering Pokemon lore questions, even those based on the games.

Comment: Lore questions are perfectly acceptable on Arqade, not sure where you're getting your info. A lore question is only off-topic if the asker is looking for a discussion based on speculation, as it sounds OP might be.